# Warning: Illegal string offset 'root'

Tags: php

I am having this error with php. The error is "Warning: Illegal string offset 'root' " this is the actual code on the line

```
$root = $atts['root'];
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you try running `var_dump($atts)` and letting us know what the output is.

Comment: `print_r($atts);` to see the complete array of $atts

Comment: All we know right now is that $atts is a string rather than the array you were expecting. You'll need to post more of the code if you want a more specific answer from us.

Comment: Ok I tried running instead "$root = var_dump($atts)['root'];"

Now this time there is no warning error instead #string(0) ""#

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, the `$var[$index]` syntax works with both **arrays** and with **strings**. With an array, this will return the element at index `$index` in array `$var` (`$index` can either be a string, meaning `$var` is an associative array, or an integer, meaning it is a normal array (I'm sure there's a better term for it but I'm not familiar).

With a string, `$index` (called an **offset** in this case) can only be an integer, and will return the character at position `$index` in the string. So if you have `$var = 'this is my string';`, then `$var[2]` would return the letter 'i' from "this" (remember that indeces start at 0 for both arrays and strings).

So in this case, it is clear that you are expecting `$atts` to be an array, but it is in fact a string. Because of this you cannot retrieve an index from another string ('root'), rather only an integer. For this reason, you are getting the error, which pretty much sums up what I wrote above. Using a string as an index, or an offset, for another string, is illegal (you can only use integers).

Without seeing more of your code I won't be able to tell why `$atts` is a string and not an array as you expect, but this will hopefully help you understand why you are getting that error.